# How to get selected value of star rating on submit form

Tags: rating

I'd like to gte the selected value of this ajax star rating :

```
<span id="stars-cap"></span>
  <div id="stars-wrapper2">
     <select name="selrate">
         <option value="1">Déplorable</option>
         <option value="2">Pas satisfaisant</option>
         <option value="3">Correct</option>
         <option value="4" selected="selected">Très satisfaisant</option>
         <option value="5">Parfait</option>
     </select>
```

I have 4 blocks 
After rating, the user must submit a form.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

give your select an id like `selrate` and then use

```
document.getElementById('selrate').value
```

Comment: No it's dont run, you can see the test page : http://www.developper-photo.com/tpl/avis-labos.php